# jquery, time out another jquery function if a user clicks a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script which fades in multiple divs called 'noti_box'. If a user closes these divs then another div 'advert' fades in in its place.

```
<script>        
$(document).ready(function(){
    var animations = [];

    $('.noti_box').each(function(i) {
        animations.push(
           $(this).hide().delay(i * 1000).fadeIn(1500).promise()
        );
    });

    $.when.apply($, animations).done(function () {
        time=setInterval(function(){
        if ( $('.noti_box:visible').length === 0 ) {
            $(".advert").fadeIn("slow");
        } },200);
    });
});
</script>
```

this works fine, basically what happens here is my last function is stuck on a loop, where the 'advert' div fades in when 'noti_box' is not visible on the page.

However, now I want a user to click a div called 'icons' and if they do, then this should re-fade in the 'noti_box' divs and fade out the 'advert' div using this code:

```
<script>
$('.icons').click(function(){ 
    $('.advert').fadeOut('fast');
$('.noti_box).fadeIn('fast');

});

</script>
```

The problem I have here is the 'advert' div fades in and out again in the blink of an eye, without fading in my 'noti_box' div. This is because my first javascript function is still on a loop and preventing my second script from executing.

So what I need to do, I think is set a time out interval for my first script when a user clicks my div 'icon' and then clear the time out interval once the script has executed and the 'noti_box' divs are once again showing.

Can someone please show me how I would be able to do this as I am brand new to jquery. Thanks

Comment: How many divs called noti-box to start with? I want to make them objects rather than what you're doing. Much simpler and then you've done it once rather than in that for loop.

Comment: And why are you using the setInterval? That's what's causing the problem :p

Comment: @sourRaspberri there is no set number of 'noti_box' divs there can be 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 etc depending on a record held in my database. I am using set interval because my 'noti_box' divs fade in after a small delay, if I didn't have set interval in there then the 'advert' div would fade in whilst the 'noti_box' divs where still fading in, where as this way it ensures the advert div is only displayed when a user closes the noti_box divs

Comment: Ok, I'm writing something but it's been a long time since I've done something like this so may not be 100% correct but it'll get you started on the right track :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function notiBox(ele){
    this.ele=ele;
    this.ele.hide().fadeIn('slow');
    console.log("I have been born! "+ele);
}
notiBox.prototype={
    constructor:notiBox,
    advert:function(){
        var ele=this.ele;
        this.ele.fadeOut('fast',function(){ele.next('.advert').fadeIn('slow');});
    },
    fadeBack:function(){
        var ele=this.ele;
        this.ele.next('.advert').fadeOut('slow',function(){ele.fadeIn('slow');});
    },
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var timeIn=1;
    $('.noti-box').each(function(){
        var self=this;
        this.timer=setInterval(function(){self.notiBox=new notiBox($(self));clearInterval(self.timer);},1000*timeIn);
        timeIn++;
    });
    $('.icon').click(function(){
        $('.noti-box').notiBox.fadeBack();
    });
});
```

Right the above is a 'OOP' based approach to your problem. The only problem you might have with this is that your advert divs are not next to the box div. Sorry I guess your DOM elements and layout. Also my methods my not be correct because it's been so long since I've written something like that. I'll do some tests. In the mean time, could you put up some HTML? So that I can adjust my code :d